# How do pagination in JavaScript when use WebDriver Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

1.I used Webdriver sampler and write selenium -Javascript.
In Java we use" List obj= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(),'REQ_')]"));  " In java script what we use for listing?

2.In my application total  50 pages are present. and every page has 10 items are present. Now I want to click the first button then click the next button and so on..up to the button is disabled.
How is this achieved?

3.How elementToBeClickable() method is used in javascript?

4.How isEnabled() method is used in javascript?

5.and also WebDriverWait() is not worked for below example

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.linkText('More finformation...')))
var element=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText("More information..."))
element.click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

It return error-->

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 4 atjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:47
```

6.can you please provide full documentation for javascript syntax and all methods used for scripting used in WebDriver sampler.

Answer (score 0):

1. The same, `var obj = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(),'REQ_')]"))`;
2. Take a look at [while statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)
3. The same

   ```
   var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 25)
   wait.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//your-selector-here")))
   ```
4. The same

   ```
   var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(),'REQ_')]")
   var enabled = element.isEnabled()
   ```
5. Look for the [JavaDoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/overview-summary.html) for the version you're using, it might be the case that the API has changed
6. The "full" documentation available at [Using Java from Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/scripting/using-java-scripts.htm) guide, some useful examples can be found in [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Don't you want to try [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) instead of JavaScript?